# Is it possible to retrieve secure enclave data using biometrics WITHOUT passcode fallback?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, mobile

I'm saving data into secure enclave and would like to retrieve it back with ONLY biometrics. I see something similar for LAContext where I can customize the fallback but, having difficulty figuring out how to do this when trying to retrieve data. Any help appreciated thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secaccesscontrolcreateflags/2937192-biometrycurrentset ?  Does it still provide a fallback option?

Comment: `LAContext` is just a feature that lets you confirm that the user can log in with Face ID, Touch ID or manually, meaning retriving data whatever it is is a totally different story.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks a lot. This is what I did end up going with. I'm working on a library that is dependent on another that is written in obj-c. I proposed we modernize the dependency to swift and am using this as a solution for now.